# How to remove empty key elements inside a list in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I have here a List, it looks like this:
box = [('','apple','banana','orange'):4,('apple','','orange'):3,('','mango','apple','grapes',' '):5]

As you can see it's a dictionary inside a list. I want to remove the empty strings in the keys so it would output like this:

box = [('apple','banana','orange'):4,('apple','orange'):3,('mango','apple','grapes'):5]

How do I get my desired output? I've tried list comprehensions but I can't seem to do it

Comment: can you show us the exact list/dictionary you're working with? The sample data you provided isn't syntactically correct

Comment: Do you miss curly braces? If so, you can try the following:
new_dict_in_list = [{
tuple(x for x in k if x) : v 
for k,v in box[0].items()
}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `box` variable, the syntax is invalid for Python. Instead, I would store your data like the following:

```
box = {4:['', 'apple', 'banana', 'orange'], 3:['apple', '', 'orange'], 5:['', 'mango', 'apple', 'grapes', '']}
```

I have:

- replaced the outer list `[]` with a dictionary `{}`
- replaced the brackets `()` with a list `[]` for each list of items
- switched the keys with their values in the dictionary

For the future, you cannot set a list as a key in a dictionary. This will result in TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'.

To remove the `''` from inside each list of items, use the following code:

```
for value in box.values():
    for item in value:
        if item == '':
            value.remove(item)
```

Output:

```
print(box)

{4: ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'], 3: ['apple', 'orange'], 5: ['mango', 'apple', 'grapes']}
```